# Not able to add Bug from Testlink to JIRA (Required Version Number)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jira, testlink

I have Integrated JIRA from testlink using REST API. I was also able to link the failed testcase to a bug in JIRA.

But while trying to create issue in testlink there is a validation happening for Version field.

Below are the fields required for creating issue in testlink.

- Version

Version has to autopopulate with data. But not sure what data needs to be populated. Whenever I type in any data, it shows no match found and field becomes empty. Thereby, the form is not allowed to submit. Could you please let me know what data is needed for Version field.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution

--Change the connection configuration by adding **ADDING VERSION TAG**--

```
<issuetracker>
<username>username</username>
<password>password</password>
<uribase>http://localhost:8085/</uribase> [^]
<uriwsdl>http://localhost:8085/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl</uriwsdl> [^]
<uriview>http://localhost:8085/browse/</uriview> [^]
<uricreate>http://localhost:8085/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa</uricreate> [^]
<projectkey>TES</projectkey>
<userinteraction>0</userinteraction>
<issuetype>TES-1</issuetype>
<issuepriority>1</issuepriority>
<attributes>
<versions>1.0</versions>
</attributes>
</issuetracker>
```

(make sure when you change the configuration in testlink logout and relog the testlink)

After that version will load the version field.when you report the bug you can select that version number